# Copy paste row data and column headers from DataSet Visualizer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

If you use the Magnifying Glass icon while debugging to pull up the grid view for a `DataSet`, is it possible to copy all the data **including** the column names to the Clipboard? I'd like to just quickly copy-paste 2 objects into Excel for manual comparison, as they don't have 100% identical structure, but I can only seem to copy the rows themselves.

Comment: This is probably a feature request, using vs 2015 and we still can't copy data with header

Answer (score 15):

I've never found a good direct way of doing this.  Seems like a feature gap.

I do this as a work around:

1. Copy and paste the table data into excel
2. Add a watch for the table.columns property of that same data bale
3. In the Results View property of the columns property, there's the list of columns.  Select all these rows and right click-> copy values
4. Paste into excel.  You should have a list of columns across multiple rows.
5. Copy those excel rows you just pasted
6. Right click an empty cell -> Paste Options -> Transpose

And boom, you'll have a row of the column headers.  You can now copy this to the top of the table data.

Answer (score -2):

You can select all and double click on top left of the column/rows and do ctrl C a few times and then paste in excel it should work the only problem I have is I can't copy the headers for some reason

Comment: You just rephrased the question bro.